# How to use foreach loop inside of dropdownlist?

Tags: java, html, jsp, foreach, drop-down-menu

I want to iterate through an array with a foreach loop in a jsp (welcome.jsp) file and want to put "project names" in a dropdown list. But the code doesn't work.

```
<!-- dropdown menu -->
 <select name="projectList" id="arrDropdownList" >
    <c:forEach  var="name"  items="${person.getProjectList()}">
        <option value="${name}">${name}   </option>
    </c:forEach>
 </select>
```

I receive the specified data via a doPost() method (RequestPostForm.java). (arrDropdownList contains the project names)

```
 Person person = new Person(name, email, authStringEnc, arrDropdownList);
 req.setAttribute("myPerson", person);
 RequestDispatcher dispatcher = req.getRequestDispatcher("welcome.jsp");
```

So far I can only display the required project names (welcome.jsp) via a for loop on the page

```
for(Object elem : person.getProjectList())
        out.print(elem + " ");
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question does not provide details about what problems/errors you are facing.  Please read about how to ask a good question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `items="${myPerson.projectList}"`

Comment: Removed tags from title; layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the following line:

```
<c:forEach  var="name"  items="${person.getProjectList()}">
```

Here, `person` is an unknown variable in JSP. Since you are setting a `person` into `req` using `myPerson` as follows:

```
req.setAttribute("myPerson", person);
```

you can retrieve it using `myPerson` only as follows:

```
<c:forEach  var="name"  items="${myPerson.getProjectList()}">
```

or

```
<c:forEach  var="name"  items="${myPerson.projectList}">
```